# debug .NET aplication only from one IP adress

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

Here is my problem.
I have one server on the other side of the world with IP 1.2.3.4

If I put in web.config this

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />
```

everyone sees a debug, I want to set something like

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" IP="4.3.2.1" />
```

So only IP 4.3.2.1 can see debug for that site all other IPs should see like

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" />
```

is set.

Answer (score 0):

The setting says how the whole page is compiled. Then in this form it is served to all clients. If you want this, you can have two sites - one normal and one debug - and if there is one particular IP requesting your site you can redirect it to the debug version.

Comment: currently I have 2 versions 1 for my debug and another which is production, but I was wondering if this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

What do you intend to do? You are fiddling with the compilation element, that is, you try to modify the compilation of your code. Code is not compiled per-request or per-user.

If you want to reveal/hide stack traces you may want to use this instead:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
```

However, this does not allow to filter by IP except the loop-back. IP addresses are generally not a very secure way to identify a person or to prevent an authorized person from retrieving the stacktrace.

If you have remote access to the web server, you can log in and use `http://localhost` to access your web site. If you have `RemoteOnly` active, you will find the stacktrace of your error then.

If you still want to go for an IP-based approach, you might find something at [Rich Custom Error Handling with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx#customerrors_topic7). The section "Rich Custom Error Pages" mentions "Logic to display detailed information only to certain IP addresses may be included here."

(I found the article by googling for "asp.net reveal stacktrace to certain ip only")

Comment: I know that IP isn't secure way, but it good enough for me, so if this RemoteOnly could work not only with localhost and it could be set from web.config it would be great.